# Как создать панель управления JavaFX

Tags: javafx, gui

Пишу программу javaFX, надо , чтобы можно было как на скриншоте открыть слева какую-то группу панелей. И при нажатии на неё открывается та самая панель. Дк вот можно ли в javaFX сделать подобные кнопки, как на скриншоте слева.

Буду рад любой помощи)

[image: Вот пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу группы панелей, которая раскрывает кнопки присмотритесь к элементу [accordion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/accordion-titledpane.htm).
Самая обычная кнопка вам подойдет для этих целей. Дочерним элементом иконку с выравниванием ее слева, текст и пачку стилей с отступами. Касаемо открытия в правой части нужных панелей, рекомендую при инициализации всего окна загрузить их все, например в stackPane и по нажатию на кнопки менять значение видимости-невидимости, так они будут появляться без всякой задержки.

Если не хотите использовать кнопку (т.к. она потащит за собой дефолтовые стили и работать со сложной кнопкой менее удобно), то можно сделать и элементами Hbox с дочерней иконкой и текстом и повешенном на него событием клика.
Что бы кнопки или другой элемент располагались сверху вниз, оберните его в Vbox.

Левая часть может выглядеть следующим образом:

Vbox
-accordion
--Vbox
---Button/HBox
---Button/HBox
---Button/HBox
-accordion
...

Comment: Спасибо, а можно где-то почитать про добавление в stackPane

Comment: Все дочерние элементы как правило добавляются через pane.getChildren().add(Node).

Comment: StackPane Добавляет их по z индексу (друг на друга).
Можно сделать  каждую панель отдельной fxml для удобства редактирования:
                        <StackPane fx:id="acContent">
                           <children>
                              <fx:include fx:id="a" source="SettingA.fxml"  visible="false" />
                              <fx:include fx:id="b" source="SettingB.fxml"  visible="false"/>

                           </children>
                        </StackPane>